# Galois Group Lattice of $f(x) = x^3-3x+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to create the Galois group lattice and the corresponding field lattice for the polynomial $f(x) = x^3-3x+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I'm having a small issue, first I'll explain what I've done so far.

I noticed that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, and thus $f$ is indeed irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Furthermore, the splitting field $K_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ contains a root of $f$, and since $f' \neq 0$ in $K$, I know that $f$ contains no multiple roots, implying that $f$ is separable.

Finally, $f$ has discriminant $D(f) = -324$ which isn't a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, implying from a Galois theory theorem that $\text{Gal}(K_{/\mathbb{Q}}) \cong D_3 = \langle a,b \: | \: a^3=b^2=e, \: ba=a^2b \rangle$.  Hence I know that $f$ has a single real root $\alpha$ and a pair of complex conjugate roots $\beta,\overline{\beta}$, implying that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$.

Then I noticed that $i \in K$, since $\text{Re}(\beta), \text{Im}(\beta) \in K$, since $\frac{\beta+\overline{\beta}}{2} \in K$ and $\frac{\beta-\overline{\beta}}{2} \in K$, implying that: $$(\beta-\text{Re}(\beta))\text{Im}(\beta)^{-1} = i \in K \implies \mathbb{Q}(i) \subset K.$$

Now, I think I have enough to start making the lattice.  I know that:

1. $\langle e \rangle \sim K$
2. $D_3 \sim \mathbb{Q}$
3. I have to match up the groups $\langle a \rangle$, $\langle b \rangle$, $\langle ab \rangle$, and $\langle a^2b \rangle$.

Hence, I just need to find automorphisms $\sigma_a,\sigma_b$ corresponding to the generators $a,b$ of $D_3$, and I should be done.  The obvious automorphism I thought of for $\sigma_b$ was: $$\sigma_b:\begin{cases} \alpha \mapsto \alpha \\
\beta \mapsto \overline{\beta} \\\end{cases}$$

I chose this one since then $|\sigma_b|=2$, and hence has index $3$, corresponding to the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  Thus, we have that $\langle b \rangle \sim \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  This leaves $\mathbb{Q}(\beta) = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ (since the real and imaginary parts of $\beta$ are in here by above).  This is a degree $2$ extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so I figured I would want $\sigma_a$ to be the automorphism whos fixed field is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

$\textbf{(Problem starts here})$, so I need $\sigma_a$ to fix $i$, but  I don't know what $\sigma_a$ does to $\text{Re}(\beta), \text{Im}(\beta)$.  I know it $\textbf{cant}$ fix these elements (im pretty sure atleast) since if $\sigma_a$ fixed $\beta$, then it fixes $\overline{\beta}$, and hence it must fix $\alpha$ too, but this is just the identity map.

1. $\textbf{First Issue}$: I don't know what $\sigma_a$ should be, as I dont know what $\alpha,\beta$ actually are.
2. $\textbf{Second Issue}$: I still need to match $\langle ab \rangle$ and $\langle a^2b \rangle$ to intermediate fields of $K$, which I don't know yet, but I beleive this is doable once I know that $\sigma_a$ is, as then I can find out what $\sigma_a \sigma_b$ and $\sigma_a^2 \sigma_b$ both fix, and go from there.

I'd really appreciate a respond on how to proceed from here. Thanks!

Comment: You are jumping to a conclusion about $i$ being in there. After all, otherwise the same argument would show that $i$ is an element of the splitting field $L$ of $x^3-2$ even though we know that the only quadratic intermediate field of $L$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: I think $(\beta- Re(\beta))(Im(\beta))^{-1}=1$, not $i$. If $\beta=x+yi$, then $(\beta-\overline{\beta})/2=yi$, as is $\beta-x$, so their ratio is $1$.

Comment: The quadratic intermediate field is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, which in this case does turn out to be $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ (because $324=18^2$), but you need a different argument.

Comment: Also sprach Cardano: If $u=-\root3\of{2-\sqrt3}$, then you have $\alpha=u+1/u$, $\beta=\omega u+\omega^2/u$, $\overline{\beta}=\omega^2u+\omega/u$ where $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$ is a third root of unity. Observe that neither $u$ nor $\omega$ are elements of the splitting field, so the Cardano formula may not be very useful for your purposes.

Comment: And $(\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\overline{\beta})(\overline{\beta}-\alpha)$ then must be equal to one of $\pm18i$. This leads to the conclusion that the permutation of roots $\alpha\mapsto\beta\mapsto\overline{\beta}\mapsto\alpha$ comes from an automorphism that fixes $i$. Anyway, this is  pretty standard exercise in Galois theory. The lattice of intermediate fields looks pretty much like that of  $x^3-2$. You just need to substitute the roots and $\sqrt{D}$ into the appropriate slots. Do search the site!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How is $(\beta-\text{Re}(\beta))\text{Im}(\beta)^{-1} = 1$?  $\beta-\text{Re}(\beta) = iy$, and $\text{Im}(\beta)^{-1}=y^{-1}$, so you get $iyy^{-1}=i$?

Comment: If you want to extract $y$ from $\beta=x+yi$ you need $(\beta-\overline{\beta})/(2i)$ instead of $(\beta-\overline{\beta})/2$. I guess it's a matter of taste (or convention) whether the imaginary part of $x+yi$ is $y$ or $yi$.

Comment: The simplest example of your fallacy is the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.  The complex number $i$ is not an element of $K$. In spite of $K$ containing infinitely many pairs of complex conjugates $\beta,\overline{\beta}$.